# normalize mixed list of dicts/lists in python

Tags: python, algorithm, list, dictionary

I have a big dataset of addresses in following mixed formats:

1) Simple straight variant of houses and flats:

"Big District, Main Street, House 1, flat 1",

"Big District, Main Street, House 1, flat 2"

```
district
    street 
        house
            flat
            flat
```

2) Complex variant of houses, flats and buildings:

"Big District, Main Street, House 1, flat 1"

"Big District, Main Street, House 1, flat 2"

"Big District, Main Street, House 1, Building 1, flat 1"

"Big District, Main Street, House 1, Building 1, flat 2"

(So there are House 1 with flats and House 1 building 1 with flats)

```
district
    street
        house
            flat
            flat
            building
                flat
                flat
```

3) Varinat of house that only have buildings

"Big District, Main Street, House 1, Building 1, flat 1"

"Big District, Main Street, House 1, Building 1, flat 2"

"Big District, Main Street, House 1, Building 2, flat 1"

"Big District, Main Street, House 1, Building 2, flat 2"

(There is no house 1 without buildings in this case, only House 1 building 1 and  House 1 building 2)

```
district
    street
        house
            building
                flat
                flat
            building
                flat
                flat
```

Data is structured as follows:

```
    [
        {"text": "street 1",
         "level": 7,
        "children":[
            {"text": "house 1",
             "level":8,
             "children":[
                {"text": "flat 1", "level": 11},
                {"text": "flat 2", "level": 11}
             ]
            },
            {"text": "house 2",
             "level": 8,
             "children":[
                {"text": "building 1",
                 "level": 9,
                 "children":[
                    {"text": "flat 1", "level": 11}
                 ]
                },
                {"text": "flat 1", "level": 11}
             ]
            },
            {"text": "house 3",
             "children": []
            }
        ]
        }
    ]
```

What I need is a list of dicts:

```
    [
    {"level 7": "Street 1", "level 8": "house 1", "level 9": NaN, "level 11":"flat 1"},
    {"level 7": "Street 1", "level 8": "house 1", "level 9": NaN, "level 11":"flat 2"},
    {"level 7": "Street 1", "level 8": "house 2", "level 9": "building 1", "level 11":"flat 1"},
    {"level 7": "Street 1", "level 8": "house 2", "level 9": NaN, "level 11":"flat 1"},
    {"level 7": "Street 1", "level 8": "house 3", "level 9": NaN, "level 11":NaN}
    ]
```

And I'm really stuck how to make this algorithm.

Comment: please make an attempt before asking then provide a [mcve] of your attempt if you are still having issues

Comment: Recursively flatten the dict. Having said that your dict seems to have a lot of "variety", seems like you need to follow some rules to flatten.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try.

Comment: You can tweak the one mentioned [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/flattening-json-objects-in-python-f5343c794b10) as per your requirement.